# Create a PowerAutomate condition for date range

Tags: date, power-automate

I am solving a problem in PowerAutomate

I have a document library in which documents are placed.
Each document on the value in the column Validity to.
I need to solve the following: validity is less than or equal to -30 days but not less than -14 days

I use the following : `addDays(utcNow(), -30)`

[image: flow screen]

I expect a range less than or equal to 30 but not less than 14. How can I add this second condition?

Answer (score 1):

Please add another condition, which is an "And" relationship with the previous condition:
[image]